# Unable to use JWT token generated from Fiware Keyrock

Tags: fiware, authzforce, fiware-wilma, fiware-keyrock

For the Fiware security layer Keyrock version 8.0.0, Wilma version 8.0.0 and  Authzforce version release-10.0.0  are configured.
Keyrock generates a Bearer token that works properly for Orion authorization. But, the problem comes if I use a JWT token instead. I generate a JWT token  by adding the scope option in the request:

`POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:3005 Authorization: Basic MTlmMjdiZGMtMTM1My00MTY5LTkxN2ItZTI1NTVjNDYwYzUyOjU4YWIxZTFjLTBkYjktNDBmZi1hMmUyLTJjZTYyNjNlNjI1Yg== Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded grant_type=password&username=username1&password=password1&scope=jwt`

When I try to access Orion through Wilma using the below request, Wilma reports the error "**AZF domain not created for application 19f27bdc-1353-4169-917b-e2555c460c52**":
`GET /version HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:1022 Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJvcmdhbml...TgxODQzfQ.O_UgX-Jl_ng0r--uDSr8dk1AeCnJAJPS3qn6VXurhxQ`

Moreover, in Keyrock GUI for the application all *Grant Types* are selected. And, for *Token types* "JWT token" is selected.
Also in Wilma configuration property for JWT Secret is added (*PEP_TOKEN_SECRET=5e39ee34ad881b01*).
I removed a few times *az_domain* from *authzforce* table in MySQL database and recreated it by adding new roles/permissions from the Keyrock GUI, but that new domain didn't solve the problem either.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess this is a configuration issue, so it will probably more likely to be answered over as a [Keyrock Git Hub Issue](https://github.com/ging/fiware-idm/issues/293) - I'm not sure if it is on topic here on Stack Overflow.